# Android Studio Cannot resolve symbol 'Before' in import org.junit.Before

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

I am using the junit-4.12 external library package in my Android Studio project. For some reason, when I import "import org.junit.Before;" into my java class I get the error "cannot resolve symbol 'Before'" (this is also happening with 'Test'), even though I can see that the files exists in my junit package (see image). I also have the dependency listed in my gradle (see 2nd image).

I noticed that someone else asked a similar question and the response was "Make sure that if JUnit is declared as < scope>test< / scope >, that your test class is in src/test, otherwise it won't be able to see the dependency."

Maybe this is my problem, but I am not sure how to make sure that my "test class is in src/test". (I am new to android studio... so sorry if this is a simple question)

["Before" and "Test" classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjQ69.png)

[Gradle Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxyTp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue using these steps:

Step 1 : Move from Android view to Projects view

Step 2 : Now under app folder you should see libs, if you don't see it, create it

Step 3 : Drag & Drop the .jar file here, you may be get a prompt "This file does not belong to the project", just click OK

Step 4 : Now you should see the jar file under libs folder, right click on the jar file and select "Add as library", Click OK for prompt "Create Library"

Step 5 : Thats it!! Now this jar has been added.

Answer (score 7):

Using Android Studio 2.0 Beta 7

1)Go To Build > Clean Project.

2)In apps build.gradle add

```
dependencies{
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

3)Steps :

1)Go To File > Project Structure.

2)Select your app from modules.

3)Go To Dependencies. Select junit:junit:4.12.

Select Test Compile.

4)Click Ok.

Import errors should get resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Be shure you are on Debug build variant. It doesn't work, if "Release" variant is chosen.

Comment: I don't know and hope this bug is already fixed. But is was the case when I faced the issue.

Comment: only one buildVariants can works wit your instrumentationTest. If you want to use another buildVariants you should add in under your build.gradle --> testBuildType "yourBuildVariants"

Answer (score 2):

In an Android project, the normal app code lives under app/src/main.  The unit test code then lives under app/src/test, as you can see here:

[image: This screenshot of the Android Studio project view shows the difference.]

Notice that the test code area is highlighted in green.  Also, to work with unit tests, you should also set your build variants Test Artifact to "Unit Tests".

[image: Shown here]

The screen here shows it on instrumentation tests, which is the default, so you you'll need to select unit tests from the dropdown.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I have done both of those things already and the error still exists. Any other ideas of why this could be happening would be very helpful.

Comment: Where exactly is the file that is having these unexpected errors?

Answer (score 1):

I was using `testCompile` in my build.gradle.

Changing this to `androidTestCompile` fixed the issue for me.

```
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
```

Answer (score 0):

Having same issue, I've downgraded to Android Studio 2.2.6 and reimport project. No issue in 2.2.6. Filled bug report.